# Compilation issues with ntopng

Tags: sqlite, centos5, luasql

I am trying to install ntopng on CentOS 5.5. When I run the make command, during the compilation process I am getting an error related to the sqlite library. I have sqlite v3.3.6 installed.

```
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int dbvm_get_name(lua_State*)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:344: warning: converting to 'int' from 'lua_Number'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int dbvm_get_type(lua_State*)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:352: warning: converting to 'int' from 'lua_Number'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int dbvm_bind_parameter_name(lua_State*)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:501: warning: converting to 'int' from 'lua_Number'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int db_create_collation(lua_State*)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1191: error: 'sqlite3_create_collation_v2' was not declared in this scope
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: At global scope:
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1261: error: 'sqlite3_int64' has not been declared
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int db_update_hook(lua_State*)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1311: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(void*, int, const char*, const char*, int)' to 'void (*)(void*, int, const char*, const char*, sqlite_int64)'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1311: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void* sqlite3_update_hook(sqlite3*, void (*)(void*, int, const char*, const char*, sqlite_int64), void*)'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: In function 'int db_exec_callback(void*, int, char**, char**)':
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1617: warning: converting to 'int' from 'lua_Number'
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c: At global scope:
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1979: error: 'SQLITE_CREATE_VTABLE' was not declared in this scope
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1980: error: 'SQLITE_DROP_VTABLE' was not declared in this scope
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1981: error: 'SQLITE_FUNCTION' was not declared in this scope
src/../third-party/lsqlite3/lsqlite3.c:1983: error: 'SQLITE_SAVEPOINT' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [src/Lua.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by installing the latest sqlite package from source -> 3.8.10.2